# Can the appFabric replace the window services ?

Tags: service, window, appfabric

Can the appFabric replace the window services ? 
Actually what is the difference of the appFabric and the window services ?Any references or examples are welcome which sight the differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFabric is a distributed caching solution that can be used to enhance your hosting solution for more details check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312.aspx)

When the AppFabric is installed, It creates a set of windows services starts with "AppFabric" such as AppFabricCachingService and generally you don't start those services from the services console however you start them from the powershell such as `start-cachecluster`

Comment: thank for the explanation but the link you share is not available to open. it show "Content not found"

Comment: I have updated the answer with the link and here you go https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312.aspx